# Using a map to check if an id exists

Tags: c++, dictionary, lookup-tables

I'm implementing a locking mecahnism and for this I need a fast lookup wether a given Id already is locked. Now I was thinking of using a map and I'm wondering if there is some better structure for this. Basically I don't really need the map, because there is no mapping done. However, If I would use a vector, I would have to do a linear search, which would become expensive for many entries.

Now I wonder if there is some structure that allows me a similar fast lookup without the additional overhead of storing etra data.

i.E.

```
std::map<IdType, bool> locked;

// Prevent deadlock by checking if this thread already locked. Otherwise
// it can pass through.
if(locked.find(Id) != locked.end())
    lock();
```

As you can see, I don't really need the mapped value. I know that for `std::vector`, using a `bool`, it is compressed to bits. Now I wonder if I waste a lot of memory for maintaining those bools while I don't even need them anyway. Would a `char` be better or some other structure which just gives me the key lookup without the extra data?

Comment: How about using a `set` if no associativity is required ? Between, you should profile it with `vector` too. Don't get surprised if your linear search performs better that `set::find`

Comment: is this supposed to run on some memory constrained hardware? if it's to be run on a PC, don't bother optimizing a few bytes away, also there is a race condition in your check

Comment: @slawekwin https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/c-coding-standards/0321113586/ch10.html This applies here: writing std::set instead of std::map better captures the intent of the code at zero cost to the programmer, without leaving future programmers to wonder what the unused value could possibly be intended for.

Comment: @Arunmu, I already once profiled such a case, and found that for an item count below about 10 or so, the vector is faster. However, I need several hundred Ids so I know that a tree is faster. I guess the `set` si what I waslooking for. Thanks!

Comment: @H.Guijt I am not saying that map is the best choice here, I am saying that premature and micro optimizations are not a good thing. I, however, do agree that readable and understandable code is a good reason to think twice about used structures, although this question was not about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have C++0x, you could use [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set), average lookup is **O(1)**.

From the cppreference.com documentation (emphasis mine):

> ... Search, insertion, and removal have **average constant-time complexity**.
>
> Internally, the elements are not sorted in any particular order, but organized into buckets. Which bucket an element is placed into depends entirely on the hash of its value. This allows **fast access to individual elements**, since once a hash is computed, it refers to the exact bucket the element is placed into.

If you don't have C++0x, [`unordered_set`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1#Containers) should be in [TR1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1):

```
#include <tr1/unordered_set>
std::tr1::unordered_set<IdType> locked;
```

You could also use an `unordered_map`, but I guess the readers of you code would have a hard time understanding what the mapped value is used for.

---

P.S.: And keep the [Rules Of Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization) in mind ;)

Comment: and if you don't have it, use `std::set` instead - lookup is O(log n).

Comment: @MartinBonner Or use the `unordered_set` from TR1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::vector<bool>` or `boost::dynamic_bitset` under following conditions:

1. `IdType` is an integral type
2. All id values fit inside a short enough range. The memory usage will be `(length of that range)/8`, which can be a couple of orders of magnitude less than would be consumed by a `std::unordered_set<int>` or `std::set<int>` containing all elements from that range.
3. You don't have to iterate over elements of your set (just insert/remove/check presence), or iteration occurs infrequently and the performance emphasis is on insertion/removal/containment-testing operations.

In such situations a dynamic bitset is a more proper data structure (both faster and more memory efficient).